# How to get value from attribute when name of attribute is in variable?

Tags: xslt

Hi all please i need a help. I just start to learn XSLT

I need get value from attribute, but name of the attribute is always different. I can get the name of attribute

The name of atribute is for example "TEST"

THIS WORK

```
<xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@TEST "/>
```

I need do something like this, But it doesnt work as i expected :/

```
<xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
<xsl:variable name="AttrName" select="'TEST'" />
<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@$AttrName "/>
```

Is this way how to do it?? Thank U very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@*[name()=$AttrName]"/>
```

@* will return all attributes, and then you apply the condition to only get one with the matching "name()".

As an aside, you don't need to use the **thisNode** variable here if you are just checking the current node. This should work too

```
<xsl:value-of select="@*[name()=$AttrName]"/>
```

Comment: Ohh my god, THANK U very much!!! It Works. I should ask 4 hours before. I tryed a lot of thinks and nothing.